# Codeigniter Cart class?

Tags: codeigniter, shopping-cart

The problem i have with class, is strange. I can not add new product with same name like
SHIRT
If i add new SHIRT to cart, class check te name and just update quantity.
The problem is what if i have same shirt but with different color??
It only update and change quanity and change color that is already in cart?
How to disable to check name and add new product with same name?

This is what i have for update

```
$qty=$_POST['productquantity'];
$data = array(
               'id'      => $proizvodid,
               'qty'     => $qty,
               'price'   => $cena,
               'name'    => $nazivproizvoda
            );


if (count($this->cart->contents())>0)
{
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item)
{
                        if ($item['id']==$proizvodid)

                        {
                            $data = array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],
                            'qty' => $item['qty']+$qty);
                            $this->cart->update($data);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $this->cart->insert($data);                         
                        }
}
}
else
{
$this->cart->insert($data);                         
}
redirect($page);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use option in your cart.

```
$data = array(
              'id'      => $proizvodid,
              'qty'     => $qty,
              'price'   => $cena,
              'name'    => $nazivproizvoda
              'options' => array('Color' => 'Red')
            );

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

Look here the explanation http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 1):

You are checking with the `id` like this:

```
if ($item['id']==$proizvodid)
{
$data = array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],
'qty' => $item['qty']+$qty);
$this->cart->update($data);
}
```

And only updating the quantity.

Comment: NO i dont want to update only quanity, i have one product SHIRT color:black quanity:2 and second SHIRT color:red quanity:1

Comment: This `$item['id']` is this unique? if not make it unique and then save in cart.

Comment: Ok, its unique, but what if i have $item['id'] with different options like color??

Comment: Each color shirt should be a different article, adjust your frontend if you want to display them as one with a select option. Otherwise it will be impossible to keep track of how many you have left of each color etc